# makefile uses same receipe for multiple targets

Tags: make

i love this makefile but if i call 'all' or 'lab4' it will -o the name 'lab4' but build using the dbug receipe. if i call 'dbug' it will -o 'dbug' and use dbug receipe.
what am i doing wrong? 
i stole this from wiki.osdev.org/Makefile btw

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -c -Wall -Werror
DBCFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -DDEBUG -g
LDFLAGS :=
LAB := lab4

PROJDIRS := .
SRCFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.c")
HDRFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.h")
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCFILES))
DEPFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRCFILES))
TSTFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%_t,$(SRCFILES))
AUXFILES := makefile README
ALLFILES := $(SRCFILES) $(HDRFILES) $(AUXFILES)

-include $(DEPFILES) $(TSTDEPFILES)

.PHONY: all clean dist check testdrivers todolist

all: $(LAB)

$(LAB): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) -o $@

%.o: %.c makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

dbug: $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) -o $@

%.o: %.c makefile
    $(CC) $(DBCFLAGS) $< -o $@

todolist:
    -@for file in $(ALLFILES:makefile=); do grep -H -e TODO -e FIXME $$file;     done; true

dist:
    @tar czf /mnt/backup/cis27/$(LAB)-`date +%m%d%y.%H%M`.tar.gz $(ALLFILES)

clean:
    -rm *.o *~ *.d
```

Comment: *"it will -o the name 'lab4' but build using the dbug receipe"* Don't think so.  It's using the (identical) `$(LAB)` recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the makefile a little. The main difference is

```
dbug: 
    @$(MAKE) CFLAGS="$(DBCFLAGS)" LDFLAGS="$(DBLDFLAGS)"
```

So if you run `make dbug` CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are redefined again.

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS = -O2 -c -Wall -Werror
DBCFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -O0 -DDEBUG -g
LDFLAGS =
DBLDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS) -g
LAB := lab4

PROJDIRS := .
SRCFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.c")
HDRFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.h")
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCFILES))
DEPFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRCFILES))
TSTFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%_t,$(SRCFILES))
AUXFILES := makefile README
ALLFILES := $(SRCFILES) $(HDRFILES) $(AUXFILES)

-include $(DEPFILES) $(TSTDEPFILES)

.PHONY: all clean dist check testdrivers todolist

all: $(LAB)

dbug: 
        @$(MAKE) CFLAGS="$(DBCFLAGS)" LDFLAGS="$(DBLDFLAGS)"

$(LAB): $(OBJFILES)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) -o $@

%.o: %.c makefile
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

todolist:
        -@for file in $(ALLFILES:makefile=); do grep -H -e TODO -e FIXME $$file;     done; true

dist:
        @tar czf /mnt/backup/cis27/$(LAB)-`date +%m%d%y.%H%M`.tar.gz $(ALLFILES)

clean:
        -rm *.o *~ *.d
```